# Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $p|k^n$, then $p^n|k^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to prove that if $p$ is a prime and $p|k^n$, then $p^n|k^n$ but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Big hint: can you show that $p\mid k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Show that $p|k^n \Rightarrow p|k$ using the uniqueness of prime factorisation for $k$ or, conversely that any prime factor of $k^n$ must have a multiple of $n$ as it's power.

Comment: Just like the other response, thank you!

Comment: @shamu11 Happy to help. If this solved your question, please mark it as answered. If not, feel free to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The exponents of the factorization of $k^n$ are multiple of $n$. Since the exponent of $p$ in that factorization is at least $1$, it must be at least $n$.

Comment: Wow this is great! Thank you!